# Does origen support 93k multi_bin feature?

Tags: origen-sdk

The examples for generating tests in the testflow create stop_bins. However there were no examples of how to generate the 93k multi_bin node. Does this feature exist in the current origen-sdk?

output node looks like this in 93k .tf file

```
if @FLAG then
{  
   multi_bin;
}
else
{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no direct support for creating multi_bin nodes, though in time I do expect that it will be added as a result [of this effort to add support for limits tables](https://github.com/Origen-SDK/rfcs/pull/3).
In the meantime though, there is the ability to render any text and this can be used to generate what you want.

To generate the above example you could do:

```rb
if_flag :flag do
  render 'multi_bin;'
end
```

This will also work with in-line conditions, this is the same:

```rb
render 'multi_bin;', if_flag: :flag
```

Additionally, `on_pass` and `on_fail` will accept a render option:

```rb
 func :my_test, on_fail: { render: 'multi_bin;' }
```

Obviously that is creating something that will not be able to translate to other tester platforms, so the advice is to use `render` sparingly and only as a get out of jail card when you really need it.

Also note that for these examples to work you need at least OrigenTesters 0.11.1.

Comment: I got the last example to work, but the first two resulted in an error. "You must specify which generator to render content to! e.g. i.test_instance.render 'multi_bin;'

Comment: Yep I saw that too. Following the advice that error is trying to provide, changing it to `flow.render 'multi_bin;'` would work, however I think that this should be the default when just calling `render`, so I updated it.
So if you update to a newer version of origen_testers per the last sentence then it should work as written.
Please tick this answer as accepted once you get it working, then it will no longer be marked as an open/un-answered question. Thanks.